# I need to update values in an array in a BigQuery table

Tags: google-bigquery

I need to clean up some mail adresses from a nested field (in an array).

I've created a regex to recognize the adresses and update them. This works on tables where the data is not in an array but I can't get it to work for where the data I want to clean is in an array.

```
UPDATE `somedata`, UNNEST(hits) AS hits
set 
  page_url = if (regexp_contains(hits.url,"([a-zA-Z0-9._%-]+(?:@|%40)[a-zA-Z0-9._%-]+[.][a-zA-Z]{2,})"), regexp_replace(hits.url,"([a-zA-Z0-9._%-]+(?:@|%40)[a-zA-Z0-9._%-]+[.][a-zA-Z]{2,})","removed%40removed.com"), hits.url)
WHERE
       regexp_contains(hits.url,"([a-zA-Z0-9._%-]+(?:@|%40)[a-zA-Z0-9._%-]+[.][a-zA-Z]{2,})")
```

Cannot access field page on a value with type ARRAY>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can't get it to work for where the data I want to clean is in an array.

Not sure what the schema of your table, so below example is based on schema for ga_sessions_ tables from `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample` public dataset as looks like your schema might be similar so it will be easy for you to adjust to your exact use-case

```
UPDATE `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_20170801`
SET hits =  ARRAY(
    SELECT AS STRUCT * REPLACE(
      (SELECT AS STRUCT * 
        REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(pagePath,r'match_expression','replace_expression') AS pagePath) 
        FROM UNNEST([page])
      ) AS page) 
    FROM UNNEST(hits)
  )   
WHERE TRUE
```

Comment: I'm working with the analytics schema indeed, nice catch and thanks for helping me in the right directions. Still really struggling with the array though. With your query I'm able to select and change the data. But to actually update the table I need to define the WHERE.

Comment: try running your sample query: UPDATE must have a WHERE clause at [1:1]

Comment: managed to get it working by adding WHERE 1=1. Not nice but it gets me the desired result.

Comment: oh, I see - try `WHERE true` instead :o)